# Wait for every page to load in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to finish a simple script reading data from some pages. My code looks like this:

```
def parsePage (https):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("path\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(https)
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

    #All the stuff going below
```

Then, the function is executed about 200 times in a loop, each one for a different page.

What my problem is, is that if the one of mentioned 200 pages won't load whole script crashes. Is there a way to make script wait each time for a page to successfully load, and if it won't load just try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for `complete` or one of `complete` and `interactive` state of JavaScript using WebDriverWait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def parsePage (https):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("path\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(https)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        lambda d: d.execute_script('return (document.readyState == "complete" || document.readyState == "interactive")'))

    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that sounds like a perfect solution